# openldap & smbk5pwd

Tags: server, password, samba, ldap

I have OpenLDAP setup (using the official OpenLDAP Server guide from ubuntu.com). I have added samba.schema and I have working samba authentication from LDAP. However, when a user changes password it doesn't change samba password.

So far I have done:

```
apt-get install slapd-smbk5pwd
```

but I have no idea how to add it to the openldap so it starts syncing passwords. I have spend alot of time googling for solution but since OpenLDAP no longer uses slapd.conf all solutions so far are useless for me. Can somebody help me how to load the module and configure smbk5pwd?

Thank you so much!

Edit:

more information about the configuration: I have a server where I am running OpenLDAP and httpd. Users can change their password with web-interface (uses php-script to change LDAP password). Samba is running on separate server.

If I could change samba-password with commandline command or with some other script, I could implement it the the web-interface and no need for smbk5pwd to sync them. However, I haven't figured out this either. All smb-password changing seems to require samba installed.

Answer (score 0):

Just can't get that smbk5pwd to work. However, since I am using web-interface for users to change password I found a workaround using [LTB-project](https://ltb-project.org/start)

I made an additional PHP-code to change both passwords when the user updates his/her password via the web-interface. If the user uses passwd to update his/her password on ssh/telnet, samba password doesn't update and he/she has to go to the website to update it.